# Which impedance matters?

Tags: usb, impedance

In USB2.0 specification, there is a requirement of desigining its data traces to be around 90Ohms +/- 15%.

Using [this](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/edge-coupled-microstrip-impedance/) calculator, with these below data:

[image]

I got these results:

[image]

Now, question is, which value shall I make 90Ohms?

Differential? Common?

Common seems much easier to reach.

I know these calculators are far from exact and also I know impedance can't be really calculated with simple calculators like this.

Still, I wish to know which impedance of this calculator must I design to be 90Ohms in case of desigining a USB2.0 communication.

Comment: Typically tracks which are twice as wide as the substrate is thick, and a modest gap, give about the right impedance on FR4. That's why very thin substrates, or multilayer boards, are popular.

Comment: If my substrate is 1.00mm (2side PCB), I shall design with 2.00mm wide tracks with modes gap to follow this rule?

Comment: a 0.6 mm spacing with those dimensions gives about 90 ohms diff impedance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

USB has 90 ohms differential impedance.

Differential means impedance seen by a differential signal where one wire goes positive and the other wire goes negative.

Common means impedance seen by a signal where both wires have the same signal.

Answer (score 2):

90 Ohms is most likely the requirement of the differential impedance, since an impedance around 100 Ohms is very popular for differential transmission lines.